# Start up script for node.js repl

Tags: node.js, startup, read-eval-print-loop, rc, startupscript

Is there a way configure node.js's repl? I want to require jquery and underscore automatically whenever the repl starts. Is there a file (noderc?) that node.js loads when it starts the repl?

The equivalent in Python is to edit `~/.ipython/ipy_user_conf.py` with:

```
import_mod('sys os datetime re itertools functools')
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't know of any such configuration file, but if you want to have modules `foo` and `bar` be available in a REPL, you can create a file `myrepl.js` containing:

```
var myrepl = require("repl").start();
["foo", "bar"].forEach(function(modName){
    myrepl.context[modName] = require(modName); 
});
```

and you when you execute it with `node myrepl.js` you get a REPL with those modules available.

Armed with this knowledge you can put `#!/path/to/node` at the top and make it executable directly, or you could modify your version of the repl.js module (source available at https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/repl.js for inspection) or whatever :)

Comment: Excellent! I made a variation that loads the modules with aliases. var modules = {jquery: '$', underscore: '_und'};
for (var mod in modules) {
    my_repl.context[modules[mod]] = require(mod);
}

Answer (score 7):

**Feb 2017** - whilst I agree with the accepted answer, wished to add a little more commentary here.

Like to setup as follows (from home directory on my Mac)

`.node
├── node_modules
│   ├── lodash
│   └── ramda
├── package.json
└── repl.js`

Then repl.js may look like as follows:

```
const repl = require('repl');

let r = repl.start({
  ignoreUndefined: true,
  replMode: repl.REPL_MODE_STRICT
});

r.context.lodash = require('lodash');
r.context.R = require('ramda');
// add your dependencies here as you wish..
```

And finally, put an alias into your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file etc (depending on your shell prefs) - something like:

`alias noder='node ~/.node/repl.js'`

Now, to use this configuration, you just have to type `noder` from the command line. Above, I also specified that I'd always like to be in `strict mode`, and do not want `undefined` printed to the console for declarations etc.

For up-to-date information on `repl` and in particular `repl.start` options see [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/api/repl.md#replstartoptions)

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the elaboration!

Answer (score 5):

I tried this today but `.start` required an argument.  Also I think the `useGlobal:true` was important. I wound up using:

```
var myrepl=require('repl').start({useGlobal:true});
myrepl.context['myObj']=require('./myObject');
```

Saving this code in `test.js` I could do a `node test.js` then access `myObj` in REPL.

Comment: I needed this to get @nicolaskruchten's example working. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 5):

Might be a newer feature of Node.js (since this question is four years old), but [you can load and save repl history](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_features) like ipython.

```
.break - While inputting a multi-line expression, sometimes you get lost or just don't care about completing it. .break will start over.
.clear - Resets the context object to an empty object and clears any multi-line expression.
.exit - Close the I/O stream, which will cause the REPL to exit.
.help - Show this list of special commands.
.save - Save the current REPL session to a file
    .save ./file/to/save.js
.load - Load a file into the current REPL session.
    .load ./file/to/load.js
```

I can't figure out how to execute this automatically when starting the shell, but `.load something` is convenient enough for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping things simple here's what I clabbered up.

repl.js:

```
// things i want in repl
global.reload = require('require-nocache')(module) // so I can reload modules as I edit them
global.r = require('ramda') // <3 http://ramdajs.com/
// launch, also capture ref to the repl, in case i want it later
global.repl = require('repl').start()
```

I can invoke this with `node repl` which feels right, and I don't care about globals, because I am just messin' around in the repl.