# A node shell based on gnu readline

Tags: node.js, shell

Is there a shell for node which uses gnu readline internally?

As you know node shell sucks in 2 ways (among others):
<s>It doesn't have search for history</s> and it is not using gnu readline. Shells that use gnu readline (like psql, ipython, python, bash, etc) has lots of features out of the box and all share a single configuration file you set in your ~/.inputrc. For example I have good vim-mode in all above shells I listed because they all use gnu readline internally. If there's a shell for js that uses gnu readline internally too, then it'll be in harmony with my other shells.

Comment: Have you tried `rlwrap`? It lets you use readline for input in any program

Comment: Thanks, it opened a whole new door for me. But unfortunately even though I have `set editing-mode vi` and `set keymap vi` in my .inputrc `rlwrap` doesn't respect it and there's no `vi-mode`. I tried socat but it has some problems too.

Comment: vi-mode works in `rlwrap nc localhost 8000` but it doesn't work with `node`, `nesh` nor `bc`

Comment: ok I needed `-a --` consider adding it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: It doesn't support `set show-mode-in-prompt on` very well.

Comment: @Sassan: What exactly goes wrong when using `rlwrap` with `set show-mode-in-prompt on`?

Comment: It wasn't working with `NODE_NO_READLINE=1` but it works nicely with `NODE_NO_READLINE=1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) is right: `rlwrap` will work. Unfortunately, it throws away
`node`s own completion. How to avoid this is a  [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210931/can-rlwrap-use-a-wrapped-commands-own-tab-completion/9219349#9219349), so here follows a way to restore completion: *not* by feeding a <kbd>TAB</kbd> to the wrapped command and then
somehow parsing the resulting mess, but using a filter.

[Filters](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap/wiki/RlwrapFilter.pm-manpage) are small scripts that act as 
`rlwrap` plugins. The can re-write user input, command output, prompts, history and completion word lists.
They can be written in `perl` or `python` and be combined in a pipeline.

Filters can do one more trick: interact with the wrapped command behind the user's back (the `cloak_and_dagger()` method)

So if we teach `node` a new command `rlwrap_complete(prefix)` that prints a list of completions of `prefix` we can use
`cloak_and_dagger("rlwrap_complete($prefix)")` to get hold of all possibe completions, and use those for `rlwrap`s own completer.

Here is the filter, written for `node`, in `perl`, but a `python` version for a different command would look very similar:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use lib ($ENV{RLWRAP_FILTERDIR} or ".");
use RlwrapFilter;
use strict;

my $filter = new RlwrapFilter;

$filter -> completion_handler( sub {
  my($line, $prefix, @completions) = @_;
  my $command = "rlwrap_complete('$prefix')";
  my $completion_list = $filter -> cloak_and_dagger($command, "> ", 0.1); # read until we see a new prompt "> "
  my @new_completions =  grep /^$prefix/, split /\r\n/, $completion_list; # split on CRNL and weed out rubbish
  return (@completions, @new_completions);                                                  
 });

$filter -> run;
```

Now we have to teach `node` the command `rlwrap_complete()`. As `node` [doesn't use an init file like `.noderc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6769250/start-up-script-for-node-js-repl) we have to
create a REPL instance and extend it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// terminal:false disables readline (just like env NODE_NO_READLINE=1): 
var myrepl = require("repl").start({terminal:false}); 

// add REPL command rlwrap_complete(prefix) that prints a simple list of completions of prefix
myrepl.context['rlwrap_complete'] =  function(prefix) {
  myrepl.complete(prefix, function(err,data) { for (x of data[0]) {console.log(x)}});
}
```

Move the filter code to `$RLWRAP_FILTERDIR/node_complete`, save the above code as `myrepl.js` and make it executable. Then call:

```sh
$ rlwrap -z node_complete ./myrepl.js
```

... and enjoy a REPL with searchable history *and* TAB completion! Any time you press <kbd>TAB</kbd> `rlwrap` will have an (invisible) chat with `node` to come up with the right completions.

Other `rlwrap` goodies (coloured prompts, `vi` mode, additional filters) can be added if you want them.

Of course, any REPL needs to be able to do a bit of metaprogramming to access its own namespace as data before we can use the same solution as for `node`

Comment: Thanks for this in detail answer. I guess we should add `-c` to rlwrap command so that completion for `fs.<TAB>` works too, otherwise prefix will be empty string in case of `fs.<TAB>`.

Comment: @Sassan: removing the dot `.` from the list of word-breaking characters is just a _side effect_ of the `-c` a.k.a `--complete-filenames` option (the general method is by using `--break-chars`) but you are right: for Javascript you want to complete prefixes like `fs.` Your comment made me aware that the completion handler needs to _add_ the original `@completions` to `@new_completions` - if not, `rlwrap -c` will not complete on filenames. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your detailed information, I also use `-e ''` to avoid extra space after completion.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work. Under Debian bullseye, rlwrap 0.43, and Node v12.22.5 pressing tab after "foo".s, just displays a tab. Under CygWin (CYGWIN_NT-10.0-19043), Node v18.5.0, and rlwrap 0.37, pressing tab after "foo".s, just beeps.

Answer (score 3):

`rlwrap` will let you use readline for arbitrary programs.

It works best if the program doesn't (or can be convinced not to) use its own line editing. For `node` in particular, you can use:

```
NODE_NO_READLINE=1 rlwrap node
```

Comment: `NODE_NO_READLINE=1` made it much better. I know `rlwrap` accepts autocompletion via `-f` but is it possible to use the underlying dynamic repl's autocompletion? For example when I enter `fs.` and press tab is there anyway it brings the autocompletion node suggests?

Comment: @Sassan: No, alas. See the answer to [Is there a way to run rlwrap with tab completion disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210931/is-there-a-way-of-running-rlwrap-with-tab-completion-disabled)

Comment: @HansLub Yeah I read your answer there. Thanks for mentioning it here. Regarding this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210931/is-there-a-way-of-running-rlwrap-with-tab-completion-disabled#comment11958744_9219349 I was wondering if it's possible to write specific codes to handle specific REPLs. I'm talking about handling tab completion case by case at least for popular REPLs. The problem is there's not much hope for the community around node to use readline or any standard thing at all.

Comment: Because for some unknown reason they just love new things and hate old things like readline no matter what. So I have more hope handling it in rlwrap than I have in node to use readline. Node prints all completion suggestions as plain text with no pagination or magic. It should be the same for many other REPLs so if we handle this case maybe we can have auto-completion in many REPLs wrapped by rlwrap.

Comment: Feeding a TAB to the underlying command is not difficult, but interpreting what comes back is a problem (this needs the "virtual terminal emulator" mentioned in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210931/is-there-a-way-of-running-rlwrap-with-tab-completion-disabled#comment11958744_9219349)) A much more elegant solution would be to write a `node.js` function `complete(text)` that prints a list of completions, followed by e.g. `"END_OF_COMPLETIONS"` and use that in a filter, using the `cloak_and_dagger()` method that interacts with the underlying command without bothering the user.

Comment: While your answer was really helpful, Hans provided a much completer answer covering auto complete. So I thought maybe it's better to have his answer as the accepted answer.